# java.lang.IllegalStateException? How to get rid of this?

Tags: android

I am using a list view. In which i change the content or add contents when scroll. It works fine but if i navigate 2 or three times from that page, it gives an error.
The Error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131230910, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter.


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2)
    {
        Log.e("vec pos", ""+position);
        if(position == vectProductBySearch.size()-1 && scrollState == 0 && vectProductBySearch.size()>8)
        {
            Log.e("vec pos", "in if()");
            if (progDialog != null && progDialog.isShowing())
                progDialog.dismiss();
            progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ProducyBySearch.this, "",
                    "Loading... Please wait..", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    SearchByCatagory.startIndex= SearchByCatagory.startIndex+10;
                    post.getProductBySearch(AppsConstants.email, AppsConstants.password, AppsConstants.AuthenticationToken,  SearchByCatagory.CatagoryId,  SearchByCatagory.description,  SearchByCatagory.brand, SearchByCatagory.rating, AppsConstants.UserNum, SearchByCatagory.startIndex);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            deafaultAdapter.refresh(AppsConstants.vectProductBySearch);
                            if (progDialog != null && progDialog.isShowing())
                                progDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: Did you change some data in your adapter from a background thread like it says? It will be much easier for anyone here to help you out if you can post the related code from your project on here.

Comment: I have edited my code here Tim.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to force any updates from background threads to occur within the UI thread. UI's in nearly all environments/languages don't support changes from other threads

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the UiThread to modify the content of the list and when the list content changes do not forget to call youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: But then why it is working perfect for 2 or three navigation. And for more it is showing the crash in real device only, not in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

outside from the ui-thread you can do ui-operations using [post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29). 
just create a new inline runnable-object and add your code to the run()-method.
its not that beatiful but helps in most cases.

example:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.scrollTo(0, 0));

        }
    });
```